# Функция onFaceDetection is .hardware.camera никогда не вызывается

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Собственно вот код.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity
            implements Camera.FaceDetectionListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private SurfaceView face;
    private Button push_btn;
    private Button btn1;
    private ImageView faces;
    static public TextView info;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_frame);
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        push_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.push_btn);
        push_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }

    private static Camera openFrontFacingCamera()
    {
        int cameraCount = 0;
        Camera cam = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
            if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
                try {
                    cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e("ex", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        return cam;
    }

    public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
        if (faces.length > 0){
            Log.d("MyTag", "here is a face");
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
//            c = Camera.open();
            c = openFrontFacingCamera();
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
        return c;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.push_btn:
                Log.d("MyLog", "making photo...");
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                Log.d("MyLog", "making photo... OK");
                break;
            case R.id.btn1:
                Log.d("MyLog", "detecting face...");
                mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(this);
                mCamera.startFaceDetection();
                Log.d("MyLog", "was started");
        }
    }

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            info.setText("ready");
            Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, Filters.class);
            info.setText(Integer.toString(mCamera.getParameters().getMaxNumDetectedFaces()));
            intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", data);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Казалось бы стандартное использование функции в точности следуя документации. Кроме того если сделать снимок и найти на нем лицо при помощи библиотеки media.Face то оно находится без проблем. Или в новой прошивке перестали поддерживать библиотеку hardware.camera и нужно писать отдельный случай используя функции из hardware.camera2?

Android 5.1.

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.